# Find min $f$ and max $f$ where $x$ and $y$ are real numbers and $f(x,y)=2 \sin x \cos y +3 \sin x \sin y +6 \cos x $ using vectors\matrices?

Tags: matrices, vectors

> Find min $f$ and max $f$ where $x$ and $y$ are real numbers and
>   $$f(x,y)=2 \sin x \cos y +3 \sin x \sin y +6 \cos x $$

This question comes from the chapter of my book about vectors and matrices,but frankly I don't see how they come into play.

Can you guys give me some hint ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define two vectors
$$\vec u =(2\sin x,3\sin x,\sqrt{13}\cos x)$$
$$\vec v =(\cos y, \sin y, \frac6{\sqrt{13}})$$
Then
$$f(x,y)=\vec u \cdot \vec v \le \|u\|\|v\|=\sqrt{13(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)}\sqrt{\cos^2y+\sin^2y+\frac{36}{13}}$$
$$=\sqrt{13}\sqrt{\frac{13+36}{13}}=7$$
Also,
$$\vec u \cdot \vec v \ge -\|u\|\|v\|=-7$$

Comment: Where does that inequality/equality follow ?

Comment: It follows from that $\vec u \cdot \vec v = \|u\|\|v\|\cos\theta$ where $\cos \theta \le 1$.

Comment: Thanks .One last question:how do I see that min $f$ is at $-7$ from your equation ?

Comment: It also comes from $\vec u \cdot \vec v=\|u\|\|v\|\cos\theta$ where $-1\le\cos \theta\le1$.

Comment: thanks for your help,that was a neat answer !

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Try [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) .

$$f(x,y)=\lambda \nabla g(x,y)$$

Comment: That's way ooout of my league ,I am just at high school .However this might be usefull for some other reader in future,so keep it up anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality twice:  $A = 3\sin y + 2\cos y$, then $f(x,y)^2 = (A\sin x+ 6\cos x)^2\leq A^2+6^2 = A^2+36\leq 3^2+2^2+36 = 49 \Rightarrow |f(x,y)| \leq 7$. From this the max is $7$ and the min is $-7$